# Removing entry of an application from add/remove programs in c#

Tags: c#, .net, uninstallation

I have developed an installer class which removes certain folders from the base dir.However,I also want to remove the entry of another application from add/remove programs through the inst class.Could anyone suggest the solution.

Regards,
Harsh Suman

Answer (score 4):

Remove the entry from the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Comment: as long as you are cleaning it up too!

Answer (score 2):

In addition, there may be an entry that needs removing from HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products

See http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/winxp/t1073003127

Answer (score 1):

It may worth to read this forum thread:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10069013/uninstall-a-proram-by-using-c.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static void RemoveControlPanelProgram(string apllicationName)
    {
       string InstallerRegLoc = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
       RegistryKey homeKey = (Registry.LocalMachine).OpenSubKey(InstallerRegLoc, true);
       RegistryKey appSubKey = homeKey.OpenSubKey(apllicationName);
       if (null != appSubKey)
       {
         homeKey.DeleteSubKey(apllicationName);
       }
     }
```